# Decrease time with javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have an error with the `decreaseTime` function. It's built to hide a submit button and change the value of the `input` on the contact form for defined time.

On my old page it was running fine, but with JqueryMobile 1.4.5 it stops working. The name for the form is correct.

I hope somebody can help me. Thank you!

```js
seconds = 20;

function decreaseTime() {
  document.contact.submit.value = seconds;
  seconds--;
  if (seconds < 0) {
    document.contact.submit.value = 'Submit';
    document.contact.submit.disabled = false;
    return true;
  }
  setTimeout('decreaseTime()', 2000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.contact.submit.value = seconds;
  setTimeout('decreaseTime()', 2000);
}
```

Comment: Don't do `setTimeout('decreaseTime()', 2000);`, but `setTimeout(decreaseTime, 2000);`

Comment: 1) What is `document.contact` a reference to? If you relying on `id` attributes being implictly converted to globally scoped variabled you ***really, really*** shouldn't be. 2) Why are you using jQuery mobile? It hasn't been updated in 8+ years and is almost completely redundant for modern development.

Comment: *"I have an error"*: care to enlighten us about *which* error, on which line of code? Stack trace? Any debugging you did?

Comment: In the olden days people gave submit buttons a name attribute of "submit" and it would totally break form.submit() function.  Try renaming your submit button.

Comment: @James, submit was only a example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 1) contact is the name of the form, document By ID doesnt work, too.
2) Yes i know, but I dont want to change the whole content for now.

Comment: I guess an error message would help diagnose the *actual* problem and not problems introduced by irrelevant example code.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question about _code_, not your function name.

Comment: One thing you should do is ditch the `onload` attribute of the `window` object. The problem is, as soon as any other script that may be loaded is using the very same attribute, it gets overwritten, and your function won't get invoked any more (also, is your invocation potentially overwriting a value that may have been set prior to the execution of your script?) and so could cause unexpected errors. Instead wrap it up in an event listener and use something like `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (p_event) { ... }, { once: true });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restructure your code and name your variables more appropriately.

The `decreaseTime` function should wholly be responsible for the timeout loop.

```js
let contactForm, submitBtn, timeRemainingSeconds; // Global state

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onContentLoaded);

function onContentLoaded() {
  contactForm = document.forms['contact-form'];
  submitBtn = contactForm.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
  timeRemainingSeconds = 20;

  decreaseTime(); // Start the interval
}

function decreaseTime() {
  submitBtn.textContent = `Submit (${timeRemainingSeconds})`;
  if (timeRemainingSeconds-- <= 0) {
    submitBtn.textContent = 'Submit';
    submitBtn.disabled = false;
    return true;
  }
  setTimeout(decreaseTime, 1000);
}
```

```html
<form name="contact-form">
  <button type="submit" disabled></button>
</form>
```